# Is it possible to set lifetime of specific session variable on the client-side

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-api

In my website a user does some action that adds a new custom variable to the Joomla session. Is it possible to set specific lifetime of that variable in the session?

Joomla 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

Just add a second variable to the session, where that variable consists of the expiry date of the custom variable that is added. Then you can check the 2nd variable for the expiry date of the first variable.